# get wrong file size with c++ ios::ate

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to get the file size of a file with c++. The code is like this:

```
 ifstream fin(filepth, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open file:" << filepth << endl;
    }
    int len = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fin.clear();
    cout << "file length is: " << len << endl;
    cout << "file length is: " << fs::file_size(fs::path(filepth)) << endl;
```

It turns out that the method of `ios::ate` got the wrong result. What did I miss and how could I got the correct result ?

Comment: *It turns out that the method of ios::ate got the wrong result* What was the wrong result?

Comment: The number is not same as the number of bytes of the file listed by command `ls`. I got the reason, it is brought by the `int` variable, which cannot express number as large as 9G.

Comment: Return from [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::tellg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) is `pos_type`, not `int`. The wrinkle in `pos_type` is that is must be able to report `-1` which is returned on error, so either `long` (or `long long` on 32-bit) or `ssize_t` may be used.

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason of the problem. My file is about 9 gigabytes long, which cannot be expressed by a 32 bit `int` variable. I used `int64_t` and the problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Below is link for details as I think return type of file_size needs to typecast:
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5659/c17-filesystem